# Summation of square root sine

Tags: trigonometry, summation, exponential-function

Is it possible to solve this?
$$y = \sum_{N=1}^{x}\sqrt{\sin N}$$

I know it is possible to solve $$y = \sum_{N=1}^{x}{\sin N}$$ by expressing sinN as its exponential before doing geometric progression to solve it.

But unlike the above,$$\sqrt{\sin N}$$ cannot be converted to its exponential as $$Im[e^{i\frac{N}{2}}] 
= i\sin\frac{N}{2}.$$

Edited:
sinN is always positive as 0

Comment: What do you mean by 'solve'?

Comment: This sum is undefined in the reals as the sine can be negative. Do you want a complex solution ?

Comment: As Yves Daoust has noted, $\sin(N)$ may be negative, which will cause a problem with the square root, making $\Im[e^{i\frac N2}]$ being unusable this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "$Im(\dots)=i \sin$"? The imaginary part of a number is by definition real.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite sine using the complex definition:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sqrt{\sin(n)}=\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sqrt{\frac{e^{ni}-e^{-ni}}{2i}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sqrt{e^{ni}-e^{-ni}}$$

Perform binomial expansion.

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sqrt{e^{ni}-e^{-ni}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}(-1)^ke^{(1/2-k)ni}e^{-kni}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}(-1)^ke^{(1/2-2k)ni}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}(-1)^ke^{(1/2-2k)ni}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{x}e^{(1/2-2k)ni}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}\frac{(-1)^k(1-e^{((1/2-2k)i)(x+1)})}{1-e^{(1/2-2k)i}}$$

If it comes to your attention that someone could get the last line into the following form:

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}a^{1/2-k}b^k$$

Then it would equal $(a+b)^{1/2}$ and that would solve everything.  My knowledge on summations does not let me directly solve the current form so I am somewhat stuck on helping you any further.

Comment: The last expression seems much more horrible than the starting one to be honest, haha.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD The point of this was to remove the square root so it may become more 'geometrically' solvable.

Comment: Would be great if someone could put the final summation into a binomial expansion form:$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{k!\Gamma(3/2-k)}a^{1/2-k}b^{k}=(a+b)^{1/2}$$